# Make the cookie reachable using a different port than the Express Server

Tags: reactjs, express

I have an express server running on port 8880 local. The React frontend on port 3000. After logging in a user I want to store the 'access_token' using res.cookie. But that doesn't work locally. I don't see the token in the debugger. If I host the whole thing under one URL, everything works. What do I have to change so that I can reach or see the token locally from port 3000?

```
res
  .cookie("access_token", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    sameSite: "none",
    secure: true,
  })
  .status(200)
  .json(others);
```

Comment: FYI, since you set `secure: true`, the cookie will only be stored if you're using `https` for the connection.  Are you using `https` when running locally?  Also, if you remove `httpOnly: true` for local use, then you also should remove the `sameSite: "none"` because that attribute requires the secure setting or all cookies will be blocked.  See [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie/SameSite).

Comment: @jfriend00 I don't use https locally

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not using https when running locally, then you have to remove the cookie options `secure` and `sameSite` for local (non-https) use.

When using `secure`, the cookie will only be stored if the connection is `https`.

When using `sameSite: "none"` and not using `secure`, the cookie will not be stored.

Comment: But the httpOnly also not work locally

Comment: @Captai-N - `httpOnly` means that the client Javascript in the webpage itself can't access the cookie, but it's still saved in the client and sent to the server for the server to use.  Cookies such as session cookies don't need to be accessed from client-side Javascript so it makes sense to set `httpOnly`.  As best I know, the `httpOnly` doesn't have any connection to whether you're using `http` or `https` as the protocol. It should work for both as it is applicable to both.